# Prolog Unit Tests for Non-deterministic predicates

Tags: prolog, plunit

I am trying to use the Prolog Unit Tests from http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/plunit.html%27%29
It gives an example for non-deterministic predicates as

```
test(member, all(X == [a,b,c])) :-
    member(X, [a,b,c]).
```

I think it just tests for all element from the list X == [a,b,c], test if it is in the list [a,b,c]. But why does

```
test(member, all(X == [a,b,c])) :-
    member(X, [a,b,c,d]).
```

reports `wrong "all" answer:`?

Answer (score 2):

You want instead:

```
test(member, set(X == [a,b,c])) :-
    member(X, [a,b,c,d]).
```